# Creating database from dump, InnoDB tables created, ISAM tables not

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Hey I'm getting a weird issue with mysql dumps on a Linux box

Reproducing:

1. Dump from mysql on box 1, the database has a mix of InnoDB and ISAM
   tables
2. Copy the dump to box 2 Create a new database on box 2
3. Run:
   `source dumpfrombox1.sql`

The Result:

1. MySQL creates all the InnoDB tables and populates with data
2. MySQL fails to create the ISAM tables with the error: `ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/navtech/DB/mysql/mydb/myisamtable.MYI' (Errcode: 13)`

Everything I've read about that error talks about file permissions, but all the InnoDB files are being written to the same directory?

I checked `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and no entries get created when I run the import.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Manually editing the dump so that all tables are InnoDB tables, the restore works.